# Google Secure Data Connector on Windows?

Tags: google-app-engine, integration

I would like to use Google Secure Data Connector with an app engine app.  I see the offical distro for the SDC agent only includes instructions for Linux.  Can this be compiled and ran on a windows machine? Does anyone have experience with this or know of a binary distro?

Comment: [SDC should run on any platform supporting JDK 1.6](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/download). What problems exactly do you have with running SDC on Windows?

Comment: @alex Just wanted to see if this was a viable option before diving in.  I haven't looked at the source or anything yet, but the website states that linux is a prereq.  Have you used SDC on a windows platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDC is not supported on Windows, however it should be able to run if the installation scripts are adjusted for windows.  I posted a question in the SDC google group and got a response from a googler stating there is not a windows distro, however he did mention it was working internally on windows.  So perhaps it will be available in the future.  The groups post is here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-sdc/ZsrZi3pAJNg